# Как написать регулярное выражение для удаления миллисекунд в формате ISO

Tags: javascript

У меня есть дата в iso формате `2019-08-04T23:01:02.447Z`
Как написать регуляное выражение для удаления миллисекунд, что бы получилась строка такого типа `2019-08-04T23:01:02.000Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что бы получилась строка такого типа `2019-08-04T23:01:02.000Z`

Возможные варианты.

```js
var time = "2019-08-04T23:01:02.447Z"
// Первая часть выражения (.*) -> $1 остается как есть
// Вторая часть выражения (\..*$) -> 000Z заменяется
console.log(time.replace(/(.*)(\..*$)/g,'$1.000Z'))

// Возможен и второй вариант, который меняет только искомую часть
console.log(time.replace(/(\..*$)/g,'.000Z'))

// Возможен и третий вариант, который меняет только искомую часть до Z
console.log(time.replace(/(\.\d+Z)/g,'.000Z'))

// Еще стоит уделить внимяние флагу `g` возможно он вам не подходит.

var time2 = "2019-08-04T23:01:02.447Z something 2019-08-04T23:03:02.447Z"
// Возможен и третий вариант, который меняет только искомую часть до Z 
// убран флаг - g, который подразумивает глобаный поиск
console.log(time2.replace(/(\.\d+Z)/,'.000Z'))

// Когда может понадобиться флаг
console.log(time2.replace(/(\.\d+Z)/g,'.000Z'))
```

[Регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)